# What is the time complexity of this in-place array reversal?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

Is this function O(n) or O(log(n)) time complexity.

```
function reverse(array) {
  for (var i = 0, j = array.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}
```

At first glance it appears to be making n/2 iterations over the input. However, if you think about it, the actual number of lower level operations is closer to 2n.

Comment: Neither n/2 nor 2n are O(log(n)).

Comment: it is still O(n). (it grows linear with n)

Comment: please explain why for answer credit

Comment: it is `o(n/2)`.

Comment: in regard to your last remark: in terms of upper bound complexity (big-O) these operations inside the loop will always take constant time to execute (O(1)) so you can disregard these and reduce to O(n/2)

Comment: If this is n/2... then could I reverse a string of a specific length in constant time? That makes no sense. There's no way it's n/2 like most people are suggesting. I just don't know WHY.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: O(n/2) is the same as O(n), although for readers it is useful to say whether it does n or n/2 steps.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve an understanding of how to analyze the time complexity of this function in a way that is generalisable to other functions and other for loops.

Comment: The requirement of Question is not to return the expected result in the least amount of operations?

Comment: You should probably specify what n is if you want to know the difference between n/2 and 2n. Is it the length of the string, or iterations of the loop?

Comment: Well n is the length of the input array which is directly correlated to the number of loops? It doesn't matter. This right here might be the reason why it is linear. More elements = linear increase in loops. Even though the number of loops is half of the number of elements.

Comment: @Mahi please note that `o` is not `O`. Landau notation has a "small o", which has a different meaning and i do not think it is `o(n/2)`.

Comment: @Eric time complexity doesn't work in the way you suggest to make string manipulation constant time. In this case the string length can vary, and since this function depends on string length, the time complexity is bound by it.  Since these operations are deterministic, yes performing with the same length string over and over should take the same time in terms of operations, but in these analyses we don't assume a single case. Go to a tutor or your professor or peers and start asking them for help now. You will only struggle later otherwise

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So assume you have a string of length `n`
Then you have indicators `i=0`, and `j = n-1`
The loop continues until `i>=j` with `j` decrements by 1 and `i` increments by 1
This will give you a total of `n/2` iterations.
Inside the loop you have a total 3 statements meaning the loop will complete a total of `3(n/2)`. Along with that you have 1 operation outside the loop leaving us with

```
f(n) = 3(n/2)+1 which is O(n)
```

EDIT: This assumes that the loop maintaining operations(`i++`,`j--`) are trivial which is common practice when dealing with Big Oh notation

Comment: Uhm, why are we assuming that i++ (or i = i - 1) is "trivial" but data[i] = data[j] has "cost". This explanation still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: As long as those operations take the same amount of time every time, it doesn't matter how much time they take. That's what we mean by "trivial" here. If you choose to include the cost of the loop operations it just changes the constant factors (the 3, /2, and +1), which, by definition, has no effect on the final answer.