# Vue Infinite Warning in Render, with computed prop for Vuetify Select Box

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a seemingly simple problem, I need to reverse a list of objects that are coming in as a prop and display them in a vuetify select box. My template looks like this;

```
  <v-col cols="12" lg="4" xl="4">
    <v-select
      v-model="paysFor"
      label="Pays for.."
      :item-text="text"
      :item-value="value"
      :items="reverseLessons"
    ></v-select>
  </v-col>
```

I understand I cannot call .reverse() on the original list, so I used a computed property instead so;

```
props: {
    lessons: {
      default () { return [] },
      type: Array
},
computed: {
     reverseLessons () {
        const rev = this.lessons

        return rev.reverse()
    } 
}
```

My understanding is this should work? However I still get the warning, not EVERY render but it still shows up at times. The component is pretty simple, it only has a few props so I'm sure it's something I'm missing with the stuff referenced above. Any help is appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

[`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reverse) is operating by reference, therefore the original array is updated and that triggers a lot of updates. Reversal operation is O(n) complexity (see [What is the time complexity of this in-place array reversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047128/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-this-in-place-array-reversal)). To avoid this, simply clone array, for instance with destructuring :

```
const rev = [...this.lessons];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I forgot that reverse is still working on the original array.. that's my python bias slipping into my javascript lol, thank you again.